# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined error using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run my app

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

 26 | 
  27 |  useEffect(() => {
  28 |    if (roomId) {
> 29 |      db.collection("rooms")
     | ^  30 |        .doc(roomId)
  31 |        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => setRoomName(snapshot.data().name));
  32 |
```

I have already defined the rooms/messages & names in my firestore. I have imported the firebase.js file & added the firebase config as well.
Here is the piece of code in my js file from where it is throwing error.

```
import db, { auth, provider } from "./firebase";
import firebase from "firebase";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

.... code ...
function Chat() {

  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomId) {
      db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => setRoomName(snapshot.data().name));

    }
  }, [roomId]);
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Edit: This is the data base structure:
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Please post databasw structure

Comment: @Ashish I have updated the question by adding the required. Could you have a look ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `snapshot.data()` returned undefined.  This can happen if there is no document at the location you queried (/rooms/{roomId}). You should check for this case before you access properties on an object that doesn't exist.

```
.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.data();
    if (data) {
        setRoomName(data.name));
    }
    else {
        // decide what you want to do if there is no document
    }
}
```

Since we can't see your database, nor can we see the value of `roomId`, we can't say why this is happening - you will have to debug your code and data to figure that out.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding the required. Could you have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onSnapshot, try using get method

```
const getRoom = useCallback(async roomId => {
    if (roomId) {
      const room = await db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .get();
      setRoomName(room.data().name);
    }
    setRoomName(null);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  getRoom(roomId)
}, [getRoom]);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I think you got this error, while  developing a WhatsAppClone from Clever Programmer youtube channel*

> Solution: roomId value is coming like **:ctV5lYvZU33hLtT4W3pB** with colon but you have to pass roomId without colon to firebase to get the roomName.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (roomId) {
  db.collection("rooms")
    .doc(roomId.split(':')[1])   //ADD this change
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => setRoomName(snapshot.data().name));
}
}, [roomId]);
```